# How to combine appropriately wide gaps in texts with build stages in beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, teaching

I'm doing some concept check slides for a slide deck I use for teaching. (See code for a mock example.)

These concept checks are sentences with key words missing. I would like to

1. Show only the gaps in the first stage, ideally filled with dots.
2. Reveal the keywords one at a time in the subsequent build stages (similar to the way one might with `\only<>{}`.)

How can I get gaps that are exactly as wide as the word they represent and use beamer’s overlay/build stages logic to reveal the keywords one by one?

```
\begin{frame}{Best subset selection \hfill Review}
    
    The number of total predictors in the original dataset is denoted by \only<1>{\dots}\only<2->{$p$}.
          
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\mygap}[3]{\only<1-#1>{\dotuline{\phantom{#3}}}\only<#2->{#3}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Best subset selection \hfill Review}
    The number of \mygap{1}{2}{total predictors} in the original \mygap{2}{3}{dataset} is denoted by \mygap{3}{4}{$p$}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A great start! This works well if there is only one gap per slide. If there are multiple gaps and I want to reveal them progressively, however, the hardcoded `<1>` and `<2>` in the command definition won't work anymore.

Comment: @Constantin: I've just updated my answer with a version that suppports stepwise uncovering of multiple gaps.